# How to find out which port is located on a switch physically

Tags: network, networking, switchport

I'm trying to physically located a port on a switch. I know which port the mac address is connected to. The port is Gi2/0/14. But this is part of a stack. How do I know which switch this port belongs to in the network closet

Comment: Switch type/model?

Comment: Thanks fellas I was able to figure out what switch it was and which port it was on. Tracing it to the patch panel was another thing.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the switches are indeed stacked, the hardware itself will very probably offer a way to show/display the stack member number of each given switch. You'll have to look it up in the given hardware documentation. Some vendors even have a 7-segment display showing the stack member number.

Taking "Gi2/0/14" to be a hint that it's a stack of Cisco switches, chances are good that the given specimen has a "mode" button on the left side of the front plate (port side).

Repeatedly shortly pressing the mode button cylces the port LEDs through different modes of information display, such as status (Link up/down/blocked/disable), speed (1G or 100/10), Duplex, PoE, Stack Member, Stack Master or CPU load. The available modes depend on the features of the given product family.

Answer (score 0):

It is on switch 2 of the stack, but you cannot tell by looking at the stack which one is switch 2 unless you labeled it. You need to connect to the stack and try to figure out which switch is switch 2.

Answer (score 0):

cisco stackable switches has led that showing the status of switch

one of this led is show stacking status that

> if led 'master' is on then this switch is master and ports of this switch started by '1/0/1'
>
> if led 'master' is off then this switch is slave and ports of this switch started from 'x/0/1' that 'x' can be '2=<'